# Kohana Auth Framework - Run Login twice

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.3

could anybody tell me what happens if an already logged-in user sends another login request with different credentials to the Kohana ORM Auth module? Is this equal to the current user's logout and login with the new credentials?

If I look at the code I get this impression but I am not sure. Especially I don't know if I have to logout the current user before processing different login credentials.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you simply write some code and give it a try?

Comment: Taking a quick look over the API browser, I'd say that the token won't be properly deleted from the db, but you'll be logged in with the new credentials

Comment: @kingkero So the user connected to this token just changes? Is it somehow possible to use this token for a login as the previous user? (I have to admit my understanding of the auth framework is quite poor so far)

Comment: Nope, there'll be a new token with credentials etc. from the new login. Fastest way to know this would be to test it (in a local environment). I'll be able to give you a full answer in 2days